# obtener distancia en base a latitud y longitud

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Necesito obtener la distancia entre dos puntos, segun formula es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero los datos que provee google maps es lat,log y yo necesito la distancia en metros

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38, 2.18);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.35, 2.18);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    alert(event.latLng);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GMaps3` ofrece bajo librería [`geometry`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=es-419) la utilidad [`google.maps.geometry.spherical`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) la cual contiene:

> Funciones de utilidad para calcular ángulos, distancias y áreas geodésicas. El radio predeterminado es el radio de la Tierra de 6378137 metros.

Para incluirla puedes hacerlo mediate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Luego puedes usar `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` la cual:

> Devuelve la distancia, en metros, entre dos LatLngs. Opcionalmente, puede especificar un radio personalizado. El radio predeterminado es el radio de la Tierra.

Así:

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myLatlng, myLatlng2);
// distancees un valor en metros
console.log((distance/ 1000) + 'Kms');
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38, 2.18);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.35, 2.18);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alert(event.latLng);
  });

  // AQUI calculo de distancia entre los puntos
  var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myLatlng, myLatlng2);
  // distancees un valor en metros
  console.log((distance/ 1000) + 'Kms');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCK3ulYYM8GCwK-_HlZVNKvkgp-zvEebUM&"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: creo que algo pasa en el snipet, sale este error, Cannot read property 'spherical' of undefined",

Comment: una pregunta adicional, como obtengo de event.latLng solo latitud y solo longitud

Comment: @x-rw, he actualizado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

Para obtener la distancia entre dos puntos con latitud y longitud usa la formula [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) que traducida a javascript es la siguiente.

```
function getDistanciaMetros(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)
{
  rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}
  var R = 6378.137; //Radio de la tierra en km 
  var dLat = rad( lat2 - lat1 );
  var dLong = rad( lon2 - lon1 );
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(rad(lat1)) * 
  Math.cos(rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

  //aquí obtienes la distancia en metros por la conversion 1Km =1000m
  var d = R * c * 1000; 
  return d ; 
}
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta, revisare mas de Haversine