# ¿Cómo calcular la distancia más cercana en un array de coordenadas?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

un placer saludarles, me preguntaba si alguien me podría explicar como hacer para calcular la distancia entre un grupo de coordenadas.

Es decir yo tengo un array de objetos en donde me viene distintos lugares, aquí viene sus coordenadas:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "lugar1",
        "lat": 15.4997741,
        "lng": -88.03860120000002
    },
    {
        "_id": "lugar2",
        "lat": 15.5085874,
        "lng": -88.0264096
    },
   .
   .
   .
    N
]
```

Entonces entre este grupo de coordenada quiero poder calcular cual es la coordenada más cercana al P1:

```
P1: { lat: 15.5158049, lng: -88.0416823 }
```

Y como resultado quiero obtener por ejemplo algo como:

"El lugar más cercano al P1 es la coordenada del lugar1: lat: "xxx" - long: "xxx" (es un ejemplo de lo que se quiere obtener)

Estuve investigando, pensé que computeDistance de google api me ayudaría, pero no logre aplicarlo, luego mire [link](https://reviblog.net/2016/01/08/javascript-obtener-la-distancia-distancia-en-kilometros-entre-dos-puntos-dadas-por-su-latitud-y-longitud/) pero no me ayudo mucho, ya que ellos se basan en una distancia especifica y realmente no me quedo muy clara la explicación de su función. En mi caso estoy usando angular

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas siempre.

Comment: Quizá esto te pueda servir :

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146892/obtener-distancia-en-base-a-latitud-y-longitud

Comment: En [este artículo](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/how-calculate-distances-map-maps-javascript-api) del propio google tienen justo el código recomendado por ellos para calcular distancia entre dos puntos usando la Fórmula del Haversine a partir de la  latitud y longitud. Busca en el artículo la función `haversine_distance`. Y hasta te enseñan a representarlo en el mapa. Échale un vistazo.

Comment: Aquí tienes [otro artículo en español](https://ourcodeworld.co/articulos/leer/1021/como-calcular-la-distancia-entre-2-marcadores-coordenadas-en-google-maps-con-javascript) muy bueno.

Comment: Hola! Solucione, gracias por sus comentario. Al final utilice el teorema de pitagoras en un ciclo for para encontrar la coordenada más cercana a mi P1, luego añadí el metodo computeDistanceBetween() de googles map api place, para calcular la distancia en terminos de metros luego ese resultado lo converti a kilomentros y con eso pude lograr lo que queria. Que era primero encontrar la ruta más cerca y luego calcular la distancia que habia. Mil gracias!